# What is the simplest way or best topology for an 9v dc battery input to generate four 2.5v dc/250mA each isolated outputs?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I am looking for something simple, and what does not require difficult to solder surface-mount components. 
I came across a complete push-pull solution (minus transformer) using LT3999, only to find out that it would be nearly impossible for me to solder it (msop10-0.5mm with power pad). 
I would also prefer a solution without feedback from secondary, using ldo regulator instead.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of 9V battery? Good luck drawing an amp out of a PP9.

Comment: ANd explain in more detail what you mean by "isolated"

Comment: it is for a generic 9vdc to 2.5vdc power supply, it is not for audio push-pull amp; the outputs can use neither a common ground nor battery ground

Comment: I didn't say it was for an audio amp.. you said 4 by 250mA = 1 AMP.

Comment: sorry,   drawing an amp not equal to drawing an amplifier schematic, lol

Comment: actually the input does not have to be battery, just 9v to 12v dc supply, i agree a 9v battery would not last long; it is just safer

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is: Get four DC-DC isolated 1W converters like [**this one from Recom**](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/recom-power/ROE-1205S/ROE-1205S-ND/5684100), then add [**a SWITCHING DC-DC regulator**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmz10500.pdf) from 5 V to 2.5V (fully integrated, >90% efficient). You should manage to get 300+ mA from each output.

Comment: If soldering is a problem, you can try these, http://www.ebay.com/itm/best-Mini-3A-DC-DC-Converter-Adjustable-Step-down-Power-Supply-Module-/322395946879

Comment: That would be perfect for me to find a combination of small cheap converters in 1w to 3w range and piece them together. There is also a bunch of inexpensive converters on ebay too, just can't seem to find the right combination. I would like the input voltage go down to about 7vdc.